# SharedPreferences method is undefined for AChartEngine intents

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I have used the SharedPreferences method all over my app to easily pass preference and other data. Now I'\m trying to interface with AChartEngine and I'm getting this syntax error: "The method SharedPreferences(String, int) is undefined for the type AverageHoleScoreToPar".  This is the code:

```
...
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;

public class AverageHoleScoreToPar extends AbstractDemoChart {
public String getName() {
    return "getName";
}
public String getDesc() {
    return "The average temperature in 4 Greek islands (line chart)";
}
public Intent execute(Context context) {
    String PREFS_NAME = "PersistentData";    
    SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    int p1R_id = prefs.getInt("prefPrefp1R_id", 0);
    String p1R_name = prefs.getString("prefPrefp1R_name", "");
...
```

Everytime I resolve one of Android or Java's well documented intricacies, I bump into another. But it's fun (most of the time) searching for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

instead of `SharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);`

If that still doesn't work for `AverageHoleScoreToPar`, try to extend an `Application` class and store your `SharedPreferences` either in a `public static SharedPreferences` variable or just a `public` variable that you later get through `getApplicationContext();`

Here's an example with `static`:

TestApplication.java:

```
public class TestApplication extends Application
{
    public static SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        String PREFS_NAME = "PersistentData";    
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

and in your `AverageHoleScoreToPar.java`, use this:

```
public Intent execute(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = TestApplication.mPrefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
...
}
```

Don't forget to include the `Application` class in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mircea. I believe the first suggestion resolved the syntax error, but left me with a run error of some sort, and no matter how many variations I tried (based on "try this" from other web Q&A's) I was left with "prefs" being null after "SharedPreferences prefs = TestApplication.mPrefs;" was executed. Today I tried accessing sql from within AverageHoleScoreToPar and went no where with that. I just finished setting up to pass all of the arrays and variables that i would like to control as parameters. I should have gone that route in the first place. Cheers, Tom

Comment: Have you checked if `mPrefs` is `null` after the `getSharedPreferences` call in `TestApplication.onCreate` ?